# Assigning a variable into a file path

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a loop for an assignment, however I cannot work out how to assign a variable into a file path.

My intention is to assign the variable to a file path to write it into a data frame. Then I need to name the data frame using the name of the variable + DF (i.e., "variable"_DF).

I've only coded the first variable criteria, subj1. as I want to get that working before doing the other 2.

I've attached my code below.

```
    for(i in length(data_list)){
  sub1_list <- list.files("../Temp assignment data/", recursive=TRUE,pattern ='subj1')
  sub2_list <- list.files("../Temp assignment data/", recursive=TRUE,pattern ='subj2')
  sub3_list <- list.files("../Temp assignment data/", recursive=TRUE,pattern ='subj3')
  file.path <- c("../Temp assignment data/")
  if(sub1_list contains i){
    data_frame <- read.table(paste0("file.path","i"))
    assign(paste("i","DF",sep="_")) <- data.frame(read.table(file.path("i"))
  }
}
```

When I run this code I then get these errors:

```
> for(i in length(data_list)){
+   sub1_list <- list.files("../Temp assignment data/", recursive=TRUE,pattern ='subj1')
+   sub2_list <- list.files("../Temp assignment data/", recursive=TRUE,pattern ='subj2')
+   sub3_list <- list.files("../Temp assignment data/", recursive=TRUE,pattern ='subj3')
+   file.path <- c("../Temp assignment data/")
+   if(sub1_list contains i){
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"  file.path <- c("../Temp assignment data/")
  if(sub1_list contains"
>     data_frame <- read.table(paste0("file.path","i"))
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'file.pathi': No such file or directory
>     assign(paste("i","DF",sep="_")) <- data.frame(read.table(file.path("i"))
+   }
Error: unexpected '}' in:
"    assign(paste("i","DF",sep="_")) <- data.frame(read.table(file.path("i"))
  }"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
>
```

Comment: Because you have quotes around i it’s being treated as a normal string, not a variable.

Comment: What do you mean by `if(sub1_list contains i){`. That isn't valid R code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using to many quotes. I can't test it, but try this:

```
(...)

if(sub1_list contains i){
    data_frame <- read.table(paste0(file.path, i))
    assign(paste(i,"DF",sep="_")) <- data.frame(read.table(file.path(i))
  }
```